# NameError: name 'request' is not defined when trying to request user.connection and user.dn

Tags: python, django, ldap

I am trying to request the connection and the dn of the logged in user for my webapp. I currently work with LDAP and I have this ModifiableConnection class in my modify.py. A user should edit his name in a GUI-based app, and it should automatically be changed in the ldap.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, MODIFY_REPLACE


class ModifiableConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, connection, dn):
        self.conn = connection
        self.dn = dn

    def modify_attr(self, attrname, values):
        modlist = [(MODIFY_REPLACE, attrname, values)]
        self.conn.modify(dn, self.conn.user, modlist)

    @property
    def firstname(self): pass

    @firstname.setter
    def firstname(self, val):
        self.modify_attr('givenName', [val])

    @property
    def lastname(self): pass

    @lastname.setter
    def lastname(self, val):
        self.modify_attr('sn', [val])

mod_con = ModifiableConnection(request.user.connection, request.user.dn)
```

This is how I call it (views.py):

```
def edit_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        mod_con = ModifiableConnection(request.user.connection, request.user.dn)
        mod_con.firstname = request.POST['first_name']
        mod_con.lastname = request.POST['last_name']
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
else:
    form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
args = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

and this is the error I get:

> ```
> mod_con = ModifiableConnection(request.user.connection, request.user.dn)
> ```
>
> NameError: name 'request' is not defined

The error is in my modify.py. I do not really know if I have to import anything or If I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you instantiating ModifiableConnection inside the modify module, in the last line? Since that is at global level it will be executed when you import the file. You already instantiate the object in your view, correctly passing the request.

You should just remove that final line in modify.py.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Roseman. My bad, I oversaw this. But after I did that, I got the error: 'User' object has no attribute 'connection' and 'dn'. Do I have to change anything in my model?

Comment: I don't know. What are those attributes, where are they supposed to be coming from, and where are you setting them?

Comment: They are supposed to come from the settings.py. Because I use the django-auth-ldap library. I just don't know how to get the dn of the logged in user.